# Python Discord, check member status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to implement a function in my discord bot that check if any member has gone offline and then execute the following functions. I have read the API reference pages but couldn't quite understan how to do it, would something sort of like this work?

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before == online:
        if after == offline:
            print("{} has gone offline.".format(member))
```

I don't think the code will work as it is intended but it might provide some guidance to what I am aiming to do.

Comment: when you use decorator, you have to call your function once to run it. So you can add scheduler to call `on_memeber_update` function when it called. So scheduler will run it in the next time. for scheduler check `https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/`.

Comment: I'm not really wondering about the trigger of the `on_member_update` command, I'm interested in the code that is to come after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.status) == "online":
        if str(after.status) == "offline":
            print("{} has gone {}.".format(after.name,after.status))
```

That is if you want it to only trigger when the user has been online and goes "offline"
You can do something like

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(after.status) == "offline":
        print("{} has gone {}.".format(after.name,after.status))
```

if you want it to trigger when the user was "Idle" or "dnd" and went "offline".

Comment: @abccd True, I guess if he's "Invisible" it gets registered as "offline" and any action
(status,
game playing,
avatar,
nickname,
roles) would cause it to get printed out as well.
Nice catch!

Comment: Why compare string values and not against `Status.online` and  `Status.offline`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I was(am) getting a "NameError: name 'Status' is not defined" when I try that so I went with the one that worked. I'm probably missing something here, my code is :  if(after.status == Status.online): and then the same for offline and the rest is the same

Comment: @Tristo Did you do `from discord import Status`?  It's not a big deal either way

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Huh, I did now and it worked. Thank you, this was educational!